# Redirect from beforeEnter causes infitite cycle and does not redirect

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a problem with the nonworking redirect. I check is the user is logged in and the info is right, but when it comes to redirecting it does not redirect and just goes in this `beforeEnter` over and over again. Can somebody say what am I doing wrong?

I am presenting here my `RouteConfig` and the problem with the first `beforeEnter`.

```js
    export const routes: RouteConfig[] = [
     { path: '*', redirect: '/' },
      {
        path: '/',
    component: router_view,
    async beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
      var hasPermission = await storage.get('state').user.tokens.access;
      console.log(!!hasPermission)
      if (!!hasPermission && from.fullPath.startsWith('/')) {
        return next('profile');
      } else {
        return next()
      }
    },
    children: [
      {
        name: 'landing',
        meta: { requiresAuth: false },
        path: '',
        component: require('pages/index').default
      },
      {
        meta: { requiresAuth: true },
        path: 'seller',
        component: require('pages/seller').default,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            name: 'profile',
            redirect: 'profile'
          },
          {
            path: 'account',
            component: require('pages/seller/account').default
          },
          {
            path: 'help/:url?',
            component: require('pages/seller/help').default
          },
          {
            path: 'profile',
            component: require('pages/seller/profile').default
          },
          {
            path: 'finances/:shop?',
            name: 'finances',
            props: route => ({
              ...route.query,
              ...route.params
            }),
            component: require('pages/seller/finances').default
          },
          {
            path: 'shop',
            component: require('pages/seller/shop').default,
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                redirect: 'main'
              },
              {
                path: 'main',
                component: require('pages/seller/shop/main').default
              },
              // {
              //   path: 'rating',
              //   component: require('pages/seller/shop/rating').default
              // },
              {
                path: 'design',
                component: require('pages/seller/shop/design').default
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            path: 'invoices',
            redirect: { name: 'invoices-send' },
            component: require('pages/seller/invoices/index').default,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'send',
                name: 'invoices-send',
                component: require('pages/seller/invoices/send').default,
              },
              {
                path: 'return',
                name: 'invoices-return',
                component: require('pages/seller/invoices/return').default
              },
              {
                path: 'create-send',
                component: require('pages/seller/invoices/createInvoice').default,
              },
              {
                path: 'create-return',
                component: require('pages/seller/invoices/createInvoice').default,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            path: 'products',
            component: router_view,
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                redirect: 'all'
              },
              {
                path: 'new',
                component: require('pages/seller/products/new').default,
                children: [
                  {
                    path: '',
                    component: require('pages/seller/products/new/createproduct').default
                  },
                ]
              },
              {
                path: 'id/:productid/edit',
                component: require('pages/seller/products/new').default,
                children: [
                  {
                    path: '',
                    name: 'edit-product',
                    props: route => ({ ...route.params, ...route.query }),
                    component: require('pages/seller/products/new/createproduct').default
                  },
                  {
                    path: 'sku',
                    name: 'edit-product-sku',
                    component: require('pages/seller/products/new/createsku').default,
                  },
                ]
              },
              {
                path: 'invoices',
                redirect: { name: 'invoices-send' }
              },
              {
                path: 'id/:productid',
                component: require('pages/seller/products/_productid').default,
                children: [
                  {
                    path: 'main',
                    name: 'product-page-solo',
                    component: require('pages/seller/products/_productid/main').default
                  },
                  // {
                  //   path: 'reviews',
                  //   component: require('pages/seller/products/_productid/reviews').default
                  // },
                  // {
                  //   path: 'statistics',
                  //   component: require('pages/seller/products/_productid/statistics').default
                  // },
                  {
                    path: 'printlabels',
                    name: 'product-labels-solo',
                    component: require('pages/seller/products/_productid/printlabels').default
                  },
                ]
              },
              {
                path: 'stickers',
                name: 'products-stickers',
                component: require('pages/seller/products/stickers').default,
              },
              {
                path: ':table',
                name: 'product-list',
                component: require('pages/seller/products/index').default,
                props: _ => ({
                  tabletype: _.params.table
                }),
                beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
                  if (to.params.table === 'invoices') {
                    return next({ name: 'invoices' });
                  } else {
                    next();
                  }
                },
                children: [
                  {
                    path: 'id/:productid',
                    component: require('pages/seller/products/_productid').default,
                    children: [
                      {
                        path: 'main',
                        name: 'product-page',
                        component: require('pages/seller/products/_productid/main').default
                      },
                      // {
                      //   path: 'reviews',
                      //   component: require('pages/seller/products/_productid/reviews').default
                      // },
                      // {
                      //   path: 'statistics',
                      //   component: require('pages/seller/products/_productid/statistics').default
                      // },
                      {
                        path: 'printlabels',
                        name: 'product-labels',
                        component: require('pages/seller/products/_productid/printlabels').default
                      },
                    ]
                  },
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        meta: { requiresAuth: false },
        name: 'signin',
        path: '/signin',
        component: router_view,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            name: 'signin',
            component: require('pages/signin/index').default
          },
          {
            path: 'restore',
            component: router_view,
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                component: require('pages/signin/restore/index').default
              },
              {
                path: 'password',
                component: require('pages/signin/restore/newpassword').default,
                beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
                  if (from.fullPath.startsWith('/confirm'))
                    return next();
                  else
                    return next('/');
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'confirm',
        meta: { requiresAuth: false },
        component: require('pages/confirm/index').default,
        beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
          const path = from.fullPath ? from.fullPath : from.path;

          if (path === '/signin' || path === '/signup' || path === '/signin/' || path === '/signup/' || path === '/' || path === '/signin/restore' || path === '/signin/restore/'
          || (from.path.startsWith('/confirm') && from.query === to.query)
          || to.query.from === 'account'|| to.query.from === 'restore')
            return next();
          else
            return next('/');
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'signup',
        path: 'signup',
        meta: { requiresAuth: false },
        component: router_view,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            name: 'signup',
            component: require('pages/signup/index').default
          },
          {
            path: 'social',
            component: require('pages/signup/social').default
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        meta: { requiresAuth: false },
        path: 'terms-of-use',
        component: require('pages/terms-of-use').default
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: are you getting a router-loop on every route you are trying to access? or only when accessing the route with `name: 'profile'`?

Comment: only on profile

Comment: Alright. In your `beforeEnter`-Navigation guard update your `if`-statement:
`if (!!hasPermission && from.fullPath.startsWith('/') && to.name !== 'profile')`

Comment: nothing have changes